# using twig template for swiftmailer emal in slim framework

Tags: email, twig, slim, swiftmailer

I have inicialize my slim app with

```
    $app = new Slim([
    'view' => new Twig(),
    'templates.path' => INC_ROOT . '/app/views'
]);

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

and i my route i have this code

```
$app->get('/test-email', function() use ($app, $mailer){

    // Here I'm fetching my email template from my template directory.
    $welcomeEmail = $app->view('emails/test_email.twig');

    // Setting all needed info and passing in my email template.
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
                    ->setFrom(array('email@seznam.cz' => 'Me'))
                    ->setTo(array('email2@seznam.cz' => 'You'))
                    ->setBody($welcomeEmail)
                    ->setContentType("text/html");


    $results = $mailer->send($message);

    // Print the results, 1 = message sent!
    print($results);

});
```

the code correctly send email to address  results=1, but body from twig template is echo to screen and not to send as email. I want use twig template for generate body of the sending email.

Comment: I chamge the code to `$welcomeEmail = app->view()->render('emails/test_email.twig');
` and it seem to send email with body from twig template

Comment: If this comment fixes your issue, please create an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I create answer but Blackwood delete it

Comment: Can you create a question on Meta for this? Ask what is wrong with it.

Comment: by the way why I must use `$app->view()->render` without `$app->render` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit my code in routes to

```
$app->get('/test-email', function() use ($app, $mailer){

    // Here I'm fetching my email template from my template directory.
    $welcomeEmail = $app->view()->render('emails/test_email.twig');

    // Setting all needed info and passing in my email template.
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
                    ->setFrom(array('email@seznam.cz' => 'Me'))
                    ->setTo(array('email2@seznam.cz' => 'You'))
                    ->setBody($welcomeEmail)
                    ->setContentType("text/html");


    $results = $mailer->send($message);

    // Print the results, 1 = message sent!
    print($results);

});`
```

and now code is sending mail with body from twig templates. I think that $app->view render the tempalte to screen and $app->view()->render render it to variable

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: I think this is a complete answer

Comment: Perhaps the line of code is what you were looking for, but an answer would also explain what to do with that line of code and why it solves the problem.

Comment: This works, how do I remove the content type that is set by twig.